New to Grafana Loki queries
I am pretty new to grafana & loki & trying to figure out some simple queries maybe for you guys.
Let's say I have the below two queries and each of them returns a number.
A.
count by(count) (sum by(label_ELM_jobId) (count_over_time({label_ELM="offboard"} |~ `INFO` [$__auto])))

B.
count by(count) (sum by(label_ELM_jobId) (count_over_time({label_ELM="offboard"} |~ `ERROR` [$__auto])))

Query B results are desired & ok & I want it unchanged. But in query A I want to apply this logic: query A result - query B result = final integer. Basically, I want both these queries in a single Bar chart.
Tried this one but I don't think it works
count by(count) (sum by(label_ELM_jobId) (count_over_time({label_ELM="offboard"} |~ `INFO` [$__auto])))
 unless count by(count) (sum by(label_ELM_jobId) (count_over_time({label_ELM="offboard"} |~ `ERROR` [$__auto])))


What are you trying to achieve with this construct count by(count)? Why not a simple count? As far as I can tell there is no label count in result of your inner query (unless you modified query before pasting here?)

Also, consider taking a [tour] and checking how to properly format [code block] in your question.

Unless doesn't do what you probably think it does. It's a way of filtering dataset base on labels present in another dataset. Since here in both datasets only a single value with no labels (AKAIK) is present, unless makes no sense. If I got what you want correctly you need to simply replace unless with - in your attempts query.
